# HTML with JS not working properly in some browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, protocols, deep-linking

The code below which I found [here](https://gist.github.com/steve228uk/0d40936eb27be445608a)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                var desktopFallback = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=4KnNVK-udTU",
                mobileFallback = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=4KnNVK-udTU",
                app = "vnd.youtube://4KnNVK-udTU";

                if( /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                    window.location = app;
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location = mobileFallback;
                    }, 25);
                } else {
                    window.location = desktopFallback;
                }

                function killPopup() {
                    window.removeEventListener('pagehide', killPopup);
                }

                window.addEventListener('pagehide', killPopup);

            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is supposed to open youtube app based on the device. If it's a mobile device's browser through which the file was opened, the video must open up in the app. The code works fine in browser like FireFox. But it is not working on chrome. The app is not being opened, instead the browser version of youtube is being opened. That implies the **mobilefallback** link is being called, which is not I want.

And also if clicked from somewhere it works fine. The problem is only with Chrome. I don't know if it's some kind of chrome feature...but this is not what I need. Any help?
I can use any kind of solution. Even some other way to open up links like **vnd.youtube://4KnNVK-udTU** this directly in app.

Sorry if this info is not enough...I'll provide whatever it takes for you to help me out. ThankYou :)